# node.js : Unhandled promise rejection causes nodemon to not record error

Tags: node.js

Can anyone help me solve this problem please?

```js
 const express = require("express")

 const app = express();
 const port = 1050;
 
 app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
     res.send("This is a homepage of  my  express app with harry bhai");
 });
 
 app.get("/about", (req, res)=>{
     res.send("This is  about pages of my first express app with Harry bhai");
 });
 
 app.post("/about", (req,res)=>{
     res.send("This is post request about pages of my first express app with Harry");
 });
 
 app.listen(port, ()=>{
     console.log(`The application has started successfully on port ${port}`);
 });
```

I see the following:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Complete Webdevelopment BootCamp\htmlcssjsNodejs\Tut71writingyourfirstExpressApp\Express> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`

The application has started successfully on port 1050

rs
child_process.js:650
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: wmic process where (ParentProcessId=5200) get ProcessId 2> nul
```

and

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Complete Webdevelopment BootCamp\htmlcssjsNodejs\Tut71writingyourfirstExpressApp\Express> nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 2.0.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
The application has started successfully on port 1050
rs
child_process.js:650
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: wmic process where (ParentProcessId=5200) get ProcessId 2> nul
```

Comment: Since nodemon is not working i have to restart server with every changes in files

Comment: Please add all other information you can, such as operating system, browser or server, node.js version, and so  on.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the server with command nodemon app.js or nodemon (yourEnteryfile.js)

Comment: nodeman.js works but when i type rs or any changes made in files gives above error

Comment: You are getting those errors because you did not handle promises correctly. Try to post a copy of your code.

Comment: After intensive search what i found out is,Nodemon works only in the newer version that is node version:14.17.3 ,nodemon version:2.0.10 ,windows 10 version 2004,and above ,older version will not have nodemon working in your computer,,that means i will have to restart the server with the command --node app.js--every time i make changes to the files.

Comment: Try to install nodemon in development <npm install nodemon --save-dev> this should fix the issue. use <nodemon app> to run the server.  This will only install nodemon in your development environment.